# How to stop users from unfreezing rows on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have some frozen rows but other users (who must have edit permissions) are inadvertently unfreezing them. I have tried adding protection to the rows so they cannot edit them, but they can still unfreeze them. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One duct tape fix would be use an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) to reset row freezing every time the spreadsheet is hand edited, like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. '
      + ' It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  const enforce = [
    {
      sheetName: /^(Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i,
      frozenRows: 1,
    },
  ];
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
  enforce.some(enforce => {
    if (sheetName.match(enforce.sheetName)
      && sheet.getFrozenRows() !== enforce.frozenRows) {
      sheet.setFrozenRows(enforce.frozenRows);
    }
  })
}
```

This function will *not* do anything when the user unfreezes rows, but it will automatically re-freeze rows when the user next modifies a value in any *cell* in the sheet.

You can choose how many rows to freeze in each sheet by inserting more { objects } in the `enforce` array. Sheets are matched using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).